# How to mount non-system TrueCrypt volumes before other startup programs (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, login, boot, mount, truecrypt

I have a truecrypt volume that is automatically mounted as a favorite upon login.  However, I have other startup programs that depend on it being mounted.

How can I have the password prompt appear and be entered before the other programs run?

I don't want to use a delay, but am happy to try running truecrypt as a service (before login) or login script, if I knew how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a login script.  It runs before startup programs.

I'm not entirely sure how the login scripts themselves are triggered (it's part of the standard operating environment), but I add this line to the relevant .vbi file:

`wshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"" /auto favorites /quit", 0, True`

Comment: Care to expand on how you wrote this login script, where you put it, how TrueCrypt needs to be configured etc?

Comment: Good question.  Updated my answer